# Confusion with IC sensor functionality

Tags: sensor

There are absolute and gauge pressure sensor types as follows:

https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/gauge-pressure-sensor-ics/8212393/

https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/absolute-pressure-sensor-ics/7176527/

I need to measure the atmospheric (barometric pressure) analog way. They are both similar and I am confused which one measures the atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute measures barometric pressure.

Pressure sensors are inherently differential- some have two ports, some measure “gauge” pressure against a port open to the atmosphere, and some have a vacuum reference to measure absolute pressure.

Measuring barometric pressure to a useful degree of accuracy requires a fairly precise sensor, so often they are specialized types.

Comment: hanks but here ie.rs-online.com/web/p/absolute-pressure-sensor-ics/7176527 it also says "Vacuum Sensors -50 to -115 kPa, NXP". I need to measure the atm pressure not the vacuum. Am I interpreting it wrong?

Comment: Read the manufacturer’s datasheet, not the distributor’s blurb.

Comment: The RS blurb is badly written and confusing - negative pressure sensors are irrelevant; the device is an absolute sensor which, as has been said, is what you need..

Answer (score 1):

You need an absolute sensor. A gauge sensor measures pressure *relative* to atmospheric, and would always indicate zero.

Comment: Thanks but here https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/absolute-pressure-sensor-ics/7176527/ it also says "Vacuum Sensors -50 to -115 kPa, NXP". I need to measure the atm pressure not the vacuum. Am I interpreting it wrong?